# Combining all data into a new sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with names of and four sheets of products. 
I would like to combine all the information into a single sheet.

Here is a link to the test spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cr6emubhqVnCdhuuOwPZEgK0t9e8k4JYWehSnYrx0uI/edit?usp=sharing

as you can see in the final sheet the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query({Tea!A1:B10;Coffee!A2:B10;Water!A2:B10;Juice!A2:B10},"where Col1 is not NULL")
```